# How to edit the word "Comment" from email confirmation. Magento 2.4.2

Tags: email, order-email, edit, order-confirmation, order-confirmation-email

All i'm trying to do is change the word "comment" on the email confirmation email. Thought there might have been a comments phtml in vendor/magento_sales but there is not.
[image]

Comment: This is not magento standard afaik. You are using a module to do this. You need to figure out which module it is and change it there.

Comment: @Black thank you and you are right. Managed to sort it now.